# Show the column not null of two tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case, inner-join

I would like to join two tables and select from two columns the first one if it is not null, of the other if the first is null. As an example imagine that we have the following tables:

```
names                                    companies_to_names
--------------------------------        -----------------------------
|id_name | name    | nickname  |        | id | id_name | id_company |
--------------------------------        -----------------------------
|   1    | NULL    | manu      |        | 1  |   1     |     1      |
|   2    | Joe A.  | NULL      |        | 2  |   2     |     1      |
|   3    | Bob B.  | NULL      |        | 3  |   3     |     1      |
|   4    | NULL    | alice     |        | 4  |   4     |     1      |
|   5    | NULL    | other     |        | 5  |   5     |     2      |
--------------------------------        -----------------------------
```

And we want to show either the name, or the nickname of the guys who work for the company with id=1. Then, I want the following result:

```
--------------------
|id_name | username|
--------------------
|   1    | manu    |
|   2    | Joe A.  |
|   3    | Bob B.  |
|   4    | alice   |
--------------------
```

I was thinking in SELECT CASE WHEN, but I don't know how to do it. Something like:

```
SELECT NAMES.id_name CASE username
  WHEN NAMES.name IS NULL THEN NAMES.nickname
  WHEN NAMES.name IS NOT NULL THEN NAMES.name
  END
FROM NAMES INNER JOIN COMPANIES_TO_NAMES ON NAMES.id_name = COMPANIES_TO_NAMES.id_name;
```

Am I right?

Comment: Check out the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that shows you how to solve your problem:

```
SELECT N.id_name
    ,IFNULL(N.name, N.nickname) AS [username]
    ,CASE
      WHEN N.name IS NOT NULL THEN 'name'
      ELSE 'nickname'
    END AS [username_source]
FROM NAMES N
INNER JOIN companies_to_names C ON C.id_name = N.id_name
                                 AND C.id = 1
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: and what is about when `N.nickname is null`? :)

Comment: @MikhailTimofeev I agree that if the nickname is null, the returned username will be null but that's more a problem of database design. The question here is to show the name and if not defined, the nickname.

Comment: Both cannot be null, by design. Thank you so much

Comment: I have another question, how can I modify the query so I can see whether I retrieved the name from the N.name or N.nickname?

Comment: @Manuelarte I've edited my answer to add a new column that indicate the source used for the username value

Comment: @JoëlSalamin I tried with this IF(IFNULL(RBS.CARRIERREF, RBS.CARRIERSREF), "CARRIERSREF" , "CARRIERREF") and it also works. Anyway, thank you!